# url rewriting question

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

hey guys can you help me with this I want my url just like this - http://www.example.com/**#!**/glen

then I want to get **glen** do you have any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any data after `#` in url, because it is not sent to the server. It is only accessible to the browser via javascript (`document.location.hash`), so the best you can do is to display blank page and make XMLHttpReqest after page load that will fetch content for this page.

[+]

In case You are trying to make this url search engine friendly, [RTM](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)